# Can't access handles from a function

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide, handles

I'm trying to create a GUI using GUIDE, which reads a string through serial communication. After that it cuts out the needed numbers and puts it on the screen. I have created this function, which is executed every time when there is a line of data in the buffer of the COM port:

```
function out = intcon1(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global comPort;
a=fgetl(comPort);
disp(a);

a(a==' ') = '';
indexstart=strfind(a,'[');
indexend=strfind(a,']');
measureddata=a(indexstart(1):indexend(1));
commas=strfind(measureddata,',');

re1data=measureddata(2:(commas(1)-1));
re2data=measureddata((commas(1)+1):(commas(2)-1));
im1data=measureddata((commas(2)+1):(commas(3)-1));
im2data=measureddata((commas(3)+1):(commas(4)-1));
temp1data=measureddata((commas(4)+1):(commas(5)-1));
temp2data=measureddata((commas(5)+1):(commas(6)-1));

old_str=get(handle.re1, 'String');
new_str=strvcat(old_str, re1data);
set(handles.listbox8, 'String', re1data);
```

Now I'm trying to put the data into a listbox. This is just the first value. The problem is, that Matlab keeps saying, that the handles are not defined. But I cound already create a button which clears the listbox using the following code:

```
function clearlists_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to clearlists (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
set(handles.listbox8, 'String', '');
```

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: Is this a serial port callback using `BytesAvailableFcn`? If so you're expecting completely the wrong parameters.

Comment: Yes it is using BytesAvailableFCN. What sould be the parameters then?

Comment: Can you post the code where you create the serial object and define the BytesAvailableFCN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably defined your BytesAvailableFCN using function handle syntax without additional arguments, like this

```
s.BytesAvailableFCN = @myfun();
```

Instead, you need to define your callback using a cell array, as explained [here in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/events-and-callbacks.html#f75633). For example,

```
s.BytesAvailableFCN = {'myFun', handles};
```

`handles` must already be defined and in your workspace when that line is run.

Comment: Thank you for your help. That was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[Serial port callbacks](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_external/events-and-callbacks.html) are different to [GUIDE callbacks](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating_guis/customizing-callbacks-in-guide.html). In the case of a serial port callback your object handle is to the serial port object and the event is a serial event. There is no third argument, hence `handles` being undefined.

If you want to retrieve your GUI handles from within this function you'll need to do so explicitly, similar to the way you're retrieving the `comport` handle - incidentally getting `comport` this way is probably unnecessary since I'd imagine it's the same object the callback is already receiving as `hObject`.

Since in this case `handles` is [GUIDE-specific data](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/creating_guis/ways-to-manage-data-in-a-guide-gui.html), the 'proper' way to retrieve it
 would be:

```
handles = guidata(gcf);
```

If your GUI has multiple figures, you may need to use `findobj()` instead of `gcf()` to get the right one.

Comment: OK. But how do I define a global variable for a handle? According to Matlab, the handles of the listbox can not be defined as global or copied to a global variable.

Comment: @bdvd Sorry, turns out I'm a bit rusty on GUIDE having not touched it in years - I've checked the documentation and updated the answer accordingly.